# Couldn't get Puppeteer to click on ad-close button

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to pick up node.js and also run puppeteer and I couldn't get puppeteer to click on an element that I want it to. When I access a website, an ad will automatically pop-up and I need puppeteer to close it but it's proving to be very difficult. I have no problems in selenium but is having tonnes of issues with puppeteer. Some help here will be fantastic.

I use puppeteer to access this website [streetdirectory](https://www.streetdirectory.com/). An ad pops-up almost immediately after the page loads. The HTML link to close the ad is below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_close" onclick="global['ss_offer_cls'] = 1; close_offers_ss_n();"></a>
```

I tried many things and it didn't work. I tried `await page.click(a.btn_close)` `await page.click(#btn_close)` and this is what I am doing now and still didn't work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.streetdirectory.com/');
    closeButton = await page.evaluate((btn_close) => {
        document.getElementsByClassName(btn_close);
    });
    await page.click(closeButton)
    await page.screenshot({path: '/users/cadellteng/desktop/ss.png'})

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check behavior of page then you will find that popup is not opening at time of loading
but also it is opening after few seconds latter (When complete page has been loaded).
So Please try this

```
 await page.goto('https://www.streetdirectory.com/');
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    let offerScreen='#offers_splash_screen';
    /**
     * Check for Offer popup page
     */
    let checkForElement = await page.evaluate((sel)=>{
           let elementCheck =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
           if(elementCheck.length){
               return true
           }else return false;

    },offerScreen);
    /** 
     * If the offer popup page opened then click on 
     * close button
     */
    let closeBtn='.btn_close';
    if(checkForElement){
        console.log("Close btn .....");
           await page.waitForSelector(closeBtn);
           await page.click(closeBtn);
    }
```